# Разница между кэшированием компонента GetComponent в Awake и Start?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть ли какая-либо разница между получения компонента в Awake и Start, влияющая на запуск и производительность. Есть ли вообще смысл об этом думать?

Насколько я знаю, Start вызывается позже Awake, что навело меня на мысль, что уж легче наверное получить и узнать обо всех компонентах, до начала основного Update, чем напрягать движок перед отрисовкой первого кадра, как собственно это делает Start. Сейчас использую GetComponent только в Awake, так как он выполняется самым первым.

Заблуждаюсь ли я, и есть ли какие-то последствия моего решения?

Comment: А все ли компоненты на момент вызова Awake будут в том состоянии, в котором надо? Если да, то без разницы, когда это делать, если нет, то у вас и выбора собственно нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Знаю один такой пример c New Input System, там если делать через скрипт, то создание экземпляра нужно делать в Awake, так как потом его нужно в OnEnable обязательно активировать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Существует [разница](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652036/awake-and-start) между [Awake](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) и [Start](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html).

### Awake

- Вызывается единожды за все время жизни скрипта
- Вызывается, когда загружается экземпляр скрипта на объекте
- Вызывается сразу, как только объект стал активным (при старте игры или при активации объекта) вне зависимости от того, активен ли сам скрипт.
- Вызывается, когда все объекты на сцене уже проинициализированы, поэтому можно безопасно вызывать GetComponent'ы, GameObject.FindWithTag'и и т.п.
- Может быть использован как конструктор (см. сноску*)

### Start

- Вызывается единожды за все время жизни скрипта
- Вызывается сразу, как только **компонент** стал активным (enabled), поэтому может быть вызван не в один кадр с Awake)
- Любой Start вызывается после всех Awake, так что если объекту A нужно что-то получить от В, то инициализация B должна быть в Awake, а A - в Start
- Start, в отличие от Awake, может быть корутиной:

```
    private IEnumerator Start()
    {
        print("Before"); 
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); // Задержка
        print("After");
    }
```

---

Таким образом кэширование компонентов может производиться в обеих функциях в зависимости от ваших требований. Следует помнить, что при кэшировании компонентов в Awake или Start хорошей практикой будет добавлять скрипту аттрибут [[RequireComponent]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html)

---

* Функция `Awake()` **не** является конструктором. Она лишь *похожа* на конструктор единственный свойством: она вызывается при создании объекта, как и конструктор.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, а то очень долго пытался найти различия между ними, теперь буду знать

Comment: А ещё стало интересно, как можно использовать Awake в виде конструктора?

Comment: Конструктор - это функция, вызываемая при создании объекта. А что такое Awake? Функция, вызываемая при создании объекта! В ней, как и в конструкторе, можно проинициализировать определенные переменные. Разумеется, Awake- это НЕ конструктор, а лишь функция, похожая свойствами на него